# Deterministic Annealing Code

Tags: matlab, heuristics, np-hard, simulated-annealing

I would like to find an open source example of a code for deterministic annealing. It can be in almost any language: C, C++, MatLab/Octave, Fortran. I have already found a MatLab code for simulated annealing, so MatLab would be best. Here is a [paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvandamteaching.googlepages.com%2FABriefIntroductionToDeterministicAnn.pdf&ei=DiLiS8qZFI7AMozB1JED&usg=AFQjCNHLps7HRWXLNN5rAX5aJ5BsJbcHuQ&sig2=YSokUTOs0UszAFZ9TDiJgQ) that describes the algorithm.

> Deterministic annealing is an
>   optimization technique that attempts
>   to find a global minimum of a cost
>   function. The technique is designed to
>   be able to explore a large portion of
>   the cost surface using randomness,
>   while still performing optimization
>   using local information. The procedure
>   starts with changing the cost function
>   to introduce a notion of randomness,
>   allowing a large area to be explored.
>   Each iteration the amount of
>   randomness (measured by Shannon
>   Entropy [2]) is constrained, and a
>   local optimization of performed.
>   Gradually, the amount of imposed
>   randomness is lowered so that upon
>   termination the algorithm optimizes
>   over the original cost function,
>   yielding a solution to the original
>   problem

Answer (score 2):

The figures in the paper you link to look like Matlab figures. I suggest you contact the authors whether they're willing to share their code with you.